# Dynamically resolve property type based on another property value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript interface:

```
interface SelectProps {
    options: Option[];
    value: string[];
    onChange: (value: string[]) => void;
}
```

I want to add boolean called `isMultiple` that will change the types of the other properties.

When `isMultiple=true`

- enforce `value:string[]`
- enforce `onChange: (value: string[]) => void;`

When `isMultiple=false`

- enforce `value:string`
- enforce `onChange: (value: string) => void;`

Is it possible to dynamically set the type of other properties based on the value of one property?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It's a bit late but I hope it helps others like it helped me.

Discriminated unions, also known as tagged unions or algebraic data types can be used to solve this problem.

```ts
interface MultipleSelectProps {
    isMultiple: true;
    options: string[];
    value: string[];
    onChange: (value: string[]) => void;
}

interface SingleSelectProps {
    isMultiple: false;
    options: string[];
    value: string;
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

type SelectProps = MultipleSelectProps | SingleSelectProps;
```

Usage example:

```
function Select(props: SelectProps) {
    if (props.isMultiple) {
        const { value, onChange } = props;
        onChange(value);
    } else if (props.isMultiple === false) {
        const { value, onChange } = props;
        onChange(value);
    }
}
```

> Note: When `isMultiple` is `undefined` or `null` it is not possible to infer the specific type of `SelectProps`. In these cases is necessary to do a strict comparison `isMultiple === false`.

Source: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/03/typescript-2-0-tagged-union-types

Comment: This seems to work for the calling code but the function that accepts the `SelectProps` seems to not be able to differentiate the `onChange` call. See [this code](https://gist.github.com/styfle/58973dbe558cd7052242bdf2b4cc4b17) for an example.

Comment: That is because is multiple can be undefined or null. In those cases it is no possible to infer the specific type of `SelectProps`. Full answer [here](https://gist.github.com/styfle/58973dbe558cd7052242bdf2b4cc4b17#gistcomment-2261541)

Comment: Wonderful! If you update your answer with the usage `function Select(props: SelectProps)` then I will mark as the correct answer!

Comment: Is there any way to type check onChange `value` argument as one of `options`? So the onChange callback could also be validated against correct values? I guess `options` couldn't be dynamic in this case?

Comment: I guess I did not understood this last question. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Both of these methods result in pretty much useless documentation hovering over `SelectProps`. Since this is quite old, is there now a better way to do this that only shows relevant information when hovering over `SelectProps`?

Comment: @Timmiej93 you can use [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). In this simple exemple it gives you all the information you need. In more complex types it may be hard to read.

I would be something like this: `type SelectProps<IsMultiple = boolean> = IsMultiple extends true ? {/* */}: {/* */};`

If this is what you are looking for, I can update the answer with a complete example

Answer (score 43):

UPDATE:

Actually, it can be done easier, all that is required here is using union type like this.

```
type SelectProps = {
      isMultiple: true;
      options: string[];
      value: string[];
      onChange: (value: string[]) => void;
    } | {
      isMultiple: false;
      options: string[];
      value: string;
      onChange: (value: string) => void;
    }
```

You can make use of typescript Distributive Conditional Types
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

So your type will look like this:

```
type SelectProps<TMultiple = boolean> = TMultiple extends true
  ? {
      isMultiple: TMultiple;
      options: string[];
      value: string[];
      onChange: (value: string[]) => void;
    }
  | {
      isMultiple: TMultiple;
      options: string[];
      value: string;
      onChange: (value: string) => void;
    };
```

Here is a quick example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9jgvys

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Can I achieve something similar if "TMultiple" is a value within an Union? I mean, if the value of "isMultiple" matches '1' | '2' or not

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer btw and all you need to do is to set values '1' or '2' instead of isMultiple true/false

Comment: Really cool! Didn't know about these conditional types.
Is there any big difference between that and an union?

Comment: The "union type" is wrong in the updated example code. Currently it is as ":", but I think the correct is "|".

Answer (score 1):

I like the @Cris response.
I just refactored it in a different way to simplify it and also corrected the union symbol (: => |)

```
type SelectProps<TMultiple = boolean, T = TMultiple extends true ? string[] : string> = {
      isMultiple: TMultiple;
      options: string[];
      value: T;
      onChange: (value: T) => void;
};
```

Answer (score -5):

No, you can't do that, but here are two alternatives

(1) Use union types for `value` and `onChange`:

```
interface SelectProps {
    options: Option[];
    isMultiple: boolean;
    value: string | string[];
    onChange: (value: string | string[]) => void;
}
```

(2) Use two different interfaces for the two cases:

```
interface SelectProps {
    options: Option[];
    isMultiple: boolean;
}

interface SingleSelectProps extends SelectProps {
    value: string;
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

interface MultipleSelectProps extends SelectProps {
    value: string[];
    onChange: (value: string[]) => void;
}

function isSingle(props: SelectProps): props is SingleSelectProps {
    return !props.isMultiple;
}

function isMultiple(props: SelectProps): props is MultipleSelectProps {
    return props.isMultiple;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Option%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SelectProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20options%3A%20Option%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isMultiple%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SingleSelectProps%20extends%20SelectProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onChange%3A%20(value%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MultipleSelectProps%20extends%20SelectProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onChange%3A%20(value%3A%20string%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isSingle(props%3A%20SelectProps)%3A%20props%20is%20SingleSelectProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20!props.isMultiple%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isMultiple(props%3A%20SelectProps)%3A%20props%20is%20MultipleSelectProps%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20props.isMultiple%3B%0D%0A%7D))

Comment: An issue with the first approach is that `value` could be `string` and `onChange` could be `(value: string[]) => void`

Comment: @AntonyO'Neill Yeah, you're right. The solution in the other (accepted) answer is better.