# constructor parameter type as optional lookup property

Tags: typescript

i've just started creating constructors based on my interfaces and i'm stuck here, where "Property 'message' does not exist on type '{ message: string; } | undefined'" in the errorMessage parameter's lookup type:

```ts
interface fetchResponse {
  data:null|object|any[];
  error?:{
    message:string;
  };
};
interface FetchResponse extends fetchResponse {};
class FetchResponse {
  constructor(data:fetchResponse["data"], errorMessage?:fetchResponse["error"]["message"]) {
    this.data = data;
    this.error = errorMessage ? {
      message: errorMessage,
    } : undefined;
  };
};
```

i found the following possible ways to fix this, but i've been able to successfully implement none:

1. resolving the property of `error` based on the property of `data` (i.e if `data` is an object/array then `error` is undefined, and if `data` is null then `error` and `error.message` are defined), which *should* make it so that `error` is not possibly undefined if i'm trying to pass an `errorMessage`: the only way i found to maybe do that is with a union ([according to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705559/dynamically-resolve-property-type-based-on-another-property-value-in-typescript)), but imitating that as seen below only caused typescript to flag 2 more problems which i'm clueless about in the latter half of the code

```ts
interface fetchResponsePositive {
  data:object|any[];
};
interface fetchResponseNegative {
  data:null;
  error: {
    message:string;
  };
};

type fetchResponse = fetchResponsePositive | fetchResponseNegative;
```

2. overloading ([according to this OS post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152641/typescript-property-type-lookup-doesnt-work-with-optional-key))? this is my first ever exposure to the concept of overloading, after looking it up i understand the concept but cant figure out how to implement it here in a way that solves the issue (or whether it's even a solution to this)
3. adding a definite assertion to the `fetchResponse["error"]["message"]` lookup: i just have no idea how to do that, i placed the exclamation mark in every conceivable spot to no success

Comment: Can you just change the type of the `errorMessage` parameter to `string` instead of grabbing it from `fetchResponse["error"]["message"]`?

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is? Why do you need the `fetchResponse` and `FetchResponse` interfaces? Creating a class already creates a type. Why do you have two types with essentially the same name in addition to the class? Do you want the interface to describe the static side of the class or the instance side?

Comment: @MattDiamond i could, but i'm creating several other interfaces & classes in this pattern (some of which using more complex types) and i was hoping there's a more maintainable solution at scale

Comment: @Jimmy the former is an interface to label the object i receive in the frontend, and the latter is a class i use to construct that object in the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a utility type that should allow you to get around this issue (inspired by [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest)'s `Get` helper):

```js
type Get<T, K> = T extends undefined ? undefined : K extends keyof T ? T[K] : unknown;
```

It will fetch the type at a given key, even when the base type is optional. You can use it like this:

```js
class FetchResponse {
  constructor(data:fetchResponse["data"], errorMessage?:Get<fetchResponse["error"], "message">) {
    this.data = data;
    this.error = errorMessage ? {
      message: errorMessage,
    } : undefined;
  };
};
```

It should evaluate to `string | undefined`, which I assume is what you want. (If you don't want `undefined` there, you can always use the `Exclude` utility type to remove it from the union.)